# Reload Kubernetes ReplicationController to get newly created Service

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to reload currently running `pods` created by `replicationcontroller` to reapply newly created `services`?

Example:

I have a running pods created by `ReplicationController` config file. I have deleted a service called `mongo-svc` and recreated it again using different port. Is there a way for the pod's env file to be updated with the new IP and ports from the new `mongo-svc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the same pod to have the new service, the clean answer is no.  You *could* (I strongly suggest not to do this) run `kubectl exec <pod-name> -c <containers> -- export <service env var name>=<service env var value>`.  But your best bet is to run `kubectl delete <pod-name>` and let your replication controller handle the work.

I've ran into a similar issue for services being ran outside of kubernetes, say a DB for instance,  to address this I've been creating this https://github.com/cpg1111/kubongo which updates the service's endpoint without deleting the pods.  That same idea can also be applied to other pods in kubernetes to automate the service update.  Basically it watches a specific service, and when it's IP changes for whatever reason it updates all the pods without deleting them.  This does use the same code as `kubectl exec` however it is automated, sanitizes input and ensures the `export` is executed on all pods.

Comment: I think this is the safest answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can *restart* pods by simply deleting them: if they are linked to a Replication controller, the RC will take care of restarting them

`kubectl delete pod <your-pod-name>`

if you have a couple pods, it's easy enougth to copy/paste the pod names, but if you have many pods it can become cumbersome.

So another way to delete pods and restart them is to scale the RC down to 0 instances and back up to the number you need.

```
kubectl scale --replicas=0 rc <your-rc>
kubectl scale --replicas=<n> rc <your-rc>
```

By-the-way, you may also want to look at '[rolling-updates](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/design/simple-rolling-update.md)' to do this in a more production friendly manner, but that implies updating the RC config.

Comment: While the main point is correct, rolling-updates only work if there is something to update, if all you are trying to update the env variable for pointing to another service, deleting the pod might actually be a better option.

Comment: @Christian: to do rolling updates you need to change the RC name (updates won't work with the same name), so that's your update even if nothing was actually updated inside the RC description. The advantage is that it allows to roll updates without shutting everything down to bring it back up.

Comment: That's not true, you can do a rolling update with the same RC name.  I have a cluster with automated rolling updates with every merge into our master branches on our repos.  The only thing that changes there is the container's tags.  But if what you're trying to get at is that you *can* change the name to cause a rolling update, then yes that is true, but you do not *have to*.

Comment: ok, good to know. i don't think it used to be that way and it was annoying, so i'll try that.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with 'reapply'?

The pods to which the services point are generally selected based on labels.In other words, you can add / remove labels from the pods to include / exclude them from a service.

Read here for more information about defining services: http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/services.html#defining-a-service

And here for more information about labels: http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/labels.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: By "env file" do you mean the environment variables available to the pod  / containers? In this case, something like `MONGO_SVC_SERVICE_PORT`? I believe there isn't a way to update them because they are set at pod creation - the documentation says _"This does imply an ordering requirement - any Service that a Pod wants to access must be created before the Pod itself, or else the environment variables will not be populated."_ So I guess you might want to find an alternative, like using DNS lookup? The kubernetes DNS supports SRV queries, which gives you the port information.

Comment: I think you are right. Do I have to stop then create the replicationcontroller or is there a restart command?